# Тире или запятая и тире в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, двоеточие, точка-с-запятой

***Отсутствие слуха теперь не казалось Федору непреодолимым препятствием, — он высказывался даже в том духе, что абсолютный слух при игре на домре и не нужен.***

Это сложное предложение с союзной и бессоюзной связью, довольно простое по структуре.

Но почему автор выбрал запятую и тире? Можно здесь поставить только тире, какая разница между этими вариантами? Можно ли использовать другой знак (точку с запятой, например)?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вашему случаю соответствует такое правило постановки **запятой и тире** (см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827528.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B12%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%C2%A7463)).

> **Запятая и тире** ставятся для обозначения «перелома» первоначальной конструкции, для указания, «с одной стороны, на расчлененность предложения, а с другой — на то, что та его часть, которая следует за этим знаком препинания, делает структурный поворот от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, „углом“: *Комната наполнилась шумом отодвигаемых стульев, в углу вспыхнул огонёк спички, осветив кисть руки с длинными пальцами, испуганной курицей заклохтала какая-то барышня, — Самгину было приятно смятение, вызванное его словами* (М.Г.); *Марья села на траву, положила голову Мишки к себе на колени, — у него голова висела, до того был худ* (А.Т.); *Мне, по крайней мере, известно, что в Краснодоне остались Володя Осьмухин и Толя Орлов, — разве они будут сидеть сложа руки?* (Ф.) <...>

Также тут можно поставить и просто **тире** в значении "как следствие", см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151).

> 3. Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **тире**, если в ней содержится *следствие*, *результат* либо *вывод* из того, о чем говорится в первой части (между частями можно вставить слова *поэтому*, *тогда* и т. п.): *Я умираю — мне не к чему лгать* (Т.); *Вы раздвинете мокрый куст — вас так и обдаст накопившимся тёплым запахом ночи* (Т.); *Не было никакой возможности уйти незаметно — он вышел открыто, будто идёт на двор, и шмыгнул в огород* (Ф.). <...>

Постановка **запятой** и даже **двоеточия** тоже будет уместна, см. [там же](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151).

> 1. Если значение следствия интонационно не подчеркивается, то вместо тире между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится **запятая**: …*Я доопрошу его осторожно, он и не заметит* (Ч.); *Человек не иголка, найдём* (Ч.). <...>

> 2. В произведениях писателей-классиков вместо тире в рассматриваемом случае встречается **двоеточие**: *Делать было нечего: Марья Ивановна села в карету и поехала во дворец* (П.); *Мы ехали сзади: никто не видел* (Л.); *Мелкий дождик сеет с утра: выйти невозможно* (Т.); *Заботы, огорчения, неудачи измучили бедного батюшку до крайности: он стал недоверчив, желчен* (Дост.). <...>

Поставить **точку с запятой**, конечно же, не возбраняется (см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/#id-11%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%C2%A7128)), однако представляется, что в данном случае части бессоюзного сложного предложения тяготеют к большей связности, а точка с запятой сделала бы их более самостоятельными — есть ли такая необходимость?..

> Примечание. В бессоюзном сложном предложении части могут быть связаны по-разному: близкие по смыслу части разделяются запятой, более самостоятельные – **точкой с запятой**: *За деревянным кирпичного цвета вокзалом видны тройки, громыхают бубенчики, кричат наперебой извозчики; зимний день сер и тепел* (Бун.) – точка с запятой отграничивает часть, имеющую самостоятельный смысл, первые три части объединены общим обстоятельством (*За деревянным кирпичного цвета вокзалом*); В *траве, в кустах кизила и дикого шиповника, в виноградниках и на деревьях – повсюду заливались цикады; воздух дрожал от их звенящего, однообразного, неумолчного крика* (Купр.) – части бессоюзного предложения разделены точкой с запятой, так как сами по себе они достаточно распространены.

**ВЫВОД**

В вашем примере постановка **запятой и тире** оправдана, однако не будет ошибкой поставить просто **тире** или **запятую**. Заменить **двоеточием** или **точкой с запятой** тоже можно, хотя это может сказаться на смысле предложения не в том ключе, в каком это передано **запятой и тире**. Поэтому можете "примерить" варианты и выбрать тот, который вам больше по нраву.

1. *Отсутствие слуха теперь не казалось Федору непреодолимым препятствием, — он высказывался даже в том духе, что абсолютный слух при игре на домре и не нужен.*
2. *Отсутствие слуха теперь не казалось Федору непреодолимым препятствием — он высказывался даже в том духе, что абсолютный слух при игре на домре и не нужен.*
3. *Отсутствие слуха теперь не казалось Федору непреодолимым препятствием, он высказывался даже в том духе, что абсолютный слух при игре на домре и не нужен.*
4. *Отсутствие слуха теперь не казалось Федору непреодолимым препятствием: он высказывался даже в том духе, что абсолютный слух при игре на домре и не нужен.*
5. *Отсутствие слуха теперь не казалось Федору непреодолимым препятствием; он высказывался даже в том духе, что абсолютный слух при игре на домре и не нужен.*

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но вот именно с выбором "по нраву" у меня всегда проблемы.  Особенно, если два варианта кажутся одинаковыми. а у вас их целых пять. Не будет ошибкой! Но это чисто школьная фраза – я ее не люблю, как и весь наш школьный стандарт обучения. Так в чем здесь поворот и тем белее следствие? Запятая не подойдет по длительности паузы.  Двоеточие? Но мы ничего не поясняем и не распространяем. Отдаленности темы тоже не вижу. Так что объясните, в чем вы видите "перелом", обозначенный единым знаком, и тогда я приму ваш ответ.

Comment: Под "переломом", вероятно, имеется в виду пунктуационная граница, когда продолжается то же предложение, но уже под "другим углом": это может быть что угодно: во второй распространённой части предложения содержится следствие или вывод из первой распространённой части; меняется стиль текста; развивается "второй этап" рассуждений, начатых в первой части; описывается другое лицо, нежели в первой части, но при тех же обстоятельствах... В общем,  я бы сказал, что "перелом" здесь — это некое ослабевание (или по крайней мере своего рода изменение ) связи между частями бессоюзного предложения...

Comment: Грубо говоря, "перелом" — это граница частей бессоюзного предложения, которая показывает, что его части чем-то да существенно отличаются (стилем изложения, временными рамками, объектом описания, сменой деятельности персонажа, перехода от мыслей к действу, и наоборот...), иначе не было бы смысла ставить запятую и тире — обошлись бы чем-то одним.

Comment: Скажем, в вашем примере чувствуется переход от мыслей в 1 части ("...теперь не казалось Фёдору...") к действию во 2 ("...он высказывался..."). Само правило написано несколько образно ("перелом", "под углом"), поэтому интерпретируем как можем)))

Comment: Спасибо вам за интерес к вопросу. Мне кажется, что изменилось мнение персонажа: раньше отсутствие слуха им не допускалось, а потом он стал ДАЖЕ считать, что абсолютный слух и не нужен. Это интересный психологический момент, когда человек пытается один и тот же факт истолковать в нужную для себя сторону (автор несколько иронически говорит об этом). Ну а мне  приятно видеть вас среди отвечающих,  а то нас стало совсем немного))

Comment: Иногда такие интересные вопросы возникают, как этот, что по мере сил хочется помочь найти ответ и самому уяснить. Вот на вашем примере отыскал это правило про постановку запятой и тире с "переломами и углами", не ожидал. Так что спасибо вам, в свою очередь, за интересный вопрос:)